# How to set session timeout with Grizzly 2.2.X?

Tags: java, webserver, grizzly

I am using embedded `Grizzly 2.2.X` web server. I want to know where I can set the session-config for default session timeout. It is easy to do such thing with normal web containers.
However I still found nowhere to do this with `Grizzly`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call setMaxInactiveInterval(int) on the HttpSession object.  It's probably easiest, since Grizzly 2.2.x doesn't currently using a deployment descriptor, to call setMaxInactiveInterval() within HttpSessionListener.sessionCreated().

Comment: Thanks! Finally I use this approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
GrizzlyWebServer server;

//do your things
```

server.getSelectorThread().setKeepAliveTimeoutInSeconds(timeoutSeconds);

Comment: Thanks, however there is no more `GrizzlyWebServer` after Grizzly 2.2.x. And I can not find out a similar function like `setKeepAliveTimeoutInSeconds` ...